# How to move site from Adobe Business Catalyst to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migration, business-catalyst

I have a site that I has been created in Adobe Business Catalyst. I am not a fan of this CMS. I am looking to change it to a WordPress site. Is there any easy way to do this? Is there any kind of conversion software or service? I want to keep all the file names and redirects, etc the same.

Comment: can you export from catalyst?

Comment: I am not sure. Are you thinking there may be an export feature within the Catalyst interface?

Comment: im not familiar with catalyst but if you could export a sql,xml,csv file than you would be on your way to porting to wp (which im very familiar with :)

Comment: thanks for the info. I did not see an export feature, but I am still looking into it.

Comment: Did you figure this out? If not, I'm very familiar with both Business Catalyst and Wordpress. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: I opened a new account in Business Catalyst and manually copied over everything. I was not willing to give my clients files to a random person who has a partner membership to transfer the site over for me. That was an option, but I was not comfortable with it.

Answer (score 2):

One of my clients wanted to leave Business Catalyst and merge it with a Wordpress.com blog. The way I got around Adobe's lack of export was as follows;

1. I used my Linux Server to pull everything off the Adobe Servers using 
    
   `wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./Local/Dir Website-ULR`

   - [Tutorial Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/), Number 10

All the HTML files came down without any extensions so;

2. I copied the directory to my Mac and used Fork Lift to batch rename the files to add .html - though any renaming software will do.

The import tool for Wordpress needs an index file to find all your pages so I needed to make an index.html page with links to every post so;

3. I copied them back to the Linux machine and used

   `tree -H baseHREF ./Local/Dir`

   - depending on OS you may need to download the tree package or similar.

This then generated an onscreen HTML file in the Terminal Window so;

4. I copied the HTML code it created and put it into Dreamweaver with the rest of the site, though any software will do, to run a batch clean up of the links.

As Wordpress.com doesn't allow you to install plugins I needed to put it on a my local installation of Wordpress to do the import.

5. I then used the [Import HTML 2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/) plugin to get the pages into my local Wordpress installation

As I was moving the files to a Wordpress.com site;

6. Export from from my Wordpress and import into their blog.

I hope this helps anyone, in total it took me 12 hours to find all the tools I needed and to work out all the steps I needed. If i needed to do it again it would take up to an hour now I know how to do it.

I had more links in the post but as I'm new to the forum I was only allow 2.

Better people than I might be able tell you a quicker way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The only things that can be "exported" in Business Catalyst are E-commerce products and Web App items - they can be exported as .CSV files. You can then hire a programmer to convert them over to a format that works with Wordpress.

Exporting blogs from the Business Catalyst blog module is tricky - one way to do it is to enable RSS and copy the RSS feed and open it in excel to save it as a .CSV or .TAB file where you may be able to import the blogs or get a programmer to convert it into soomething Wordpress compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking time to better explain your platform to me.

In the way of an answer, I recommend the following:

1. Export your current web site details into a `csv` file using Screaming Frog.
2. Then use the CVS Importer WordPress Plugin

This is working for me. I would still be pleased to hear if others have found a process that they also find suitable.